# Saving vector layer into KML across 180 longitude line

Tags: google-maps, vector, layers, kml, save

I am trying to save a vector layer into KML, however in this case some of the shape cross the 180 longitude line and the shape just breaks and become long lines.. (they are supposed to be circles)

How do I save it so that the shape stay as the original image (2nd image)? 
I would like to export the file into google map with the information in the tables.

[image: shape saved to KML]

[image: Vector layer shape]

Comment: Split your linestrings into multipart lines at date line, calculating a great circle break point if necessary.